# php line in a css, but the css comes from php

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I had the issue, that I want to add a get_template_directory_uri() in a css line. This Css line is located in a boxes.php file.

```
$box_first = 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 175, 227, .8), rgba(0, 175, 227, .8)),
url("/wp/wp-content/themes/my_theme/inc/img/boxes/box2.png") center;';
```

I also tried already to make a variable and put the variable in

```
$tpl_dir = echo get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/inc/img/boxes/box2.png';
 
$box_first = 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 175, 227, .8), rgba(0, 175, 227, .8)),
url("$tpl_dir") center;';
```

, without any success..

Do you have any conclusions for me?

Many thanks and stay healthy, Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not quite sure I got your idea. Anyway, I will point out some problems here.

If you want to assign the value returned by the function, you don't have to echo it. So that `echo` can be removed like this:

```
$tpl_dir = get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/inc/img/boxes/box2.png';
```

Here, the value returned by the function (ie, the url) is appended with the path to the image.

And the second problem here is, when you want to use the value from a variable, inside a string that has single quotes for enclosing the string, try to do concatenation.

Eg:

```
$box_first = 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 175, 227, .8), rgba(0, 175, 227, .8)),
url("' . $tpl_dir . '") center;';
```

Or else, it should be enclosed in double quotes. Then only the variable inside would be parsed.

Eg:

```
$box_first = "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 175, 227, .8), rgba(0, 175, 227, .8)),
url(\"$tpl_dir\") center;";
```

Or,

```
$box_first = "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 175, 227, .8), rgba(0, 175, 227, .8)),
url('$tpl_dir') center;";
```

Also, if you are going to follow this instead of concatenation, I would suggest enclosing the variable name in curly braces.

Eg:

```
$box_first = "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 175, 227, .8), rgba(0, 175, 227, .8)),
    url(\"{$tpl_dir}\") center;";
```

Now you can use the `$box_first`  variable to style the element. Eg:

```
<div class="abc_something" style="<?php echo $box_first ; ?>">blah blah blah</div>
```

Comment: thanks in advance! I think i have a logic mistake. First at all - ("' . $tpl_dir . '") is working fine! when i define $tpl_dir with complete domain link to file - it works wonderful. Actually I tried it with a var for get_template.. $homeptth = get_template_directory_uri();
$tpl_dir1 = $homeptth . '/inc/img/boxes/box1.png'; It Seems, that it does not work with the Operator " . "

Comment: $tpl_dir1 = get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/img/boxes/box1.png'; When I Call this in a textbook the link stays in correct. I don't know where my mistake ist..

Comment: @Dennis can you please edit your question and include a screenshot and actual piece of code that you are using. And if it shows any errors, include that too. Also, please include what is the expected result.]

Comment: Thanks for this opportunity, but I do not want, that you will do my work.